# Invalid Array Index Out Bound Excception

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting Array Index out of bound exception unnecessary. I tried to do the dry run in copy but everything seems good. And in logcat I am getting this exception around if or else if condition.

```
for (int[] winningPosition : winningPos) {
    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0 && gameState[winningPosition[1]] != 1) {
        num = winningPosition[3];
        priority=true;
    }
    else if (gameState[winningPosition[1]] != 1 &&   gameState[winningPosition[3]] == 0) {
        num = winningPosition[1];
        priority=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear lord, format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used

```
num = winningPosition[3];
```

But you should use

```
num = winningPosition[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

`else if (gameState[winningPosition[1]] != 1 &&   gameState[winningPosition[3]] == 0){`

shoud be

`else if (gameState[winningPosition[1]] != 1 &&   gameState[winningPosition[2]] == 0){`

Answer (score -1):

The index is out of bound in this line.

```
winningPosition[3]
```

`winningPosition`  is come from `winningPos` which its index only range from 0 to 2.